# Get values from JTable cell with multiple CellRenderer

Tags: java, jtable, tablecellrenderer, tablecelleditor

I have **JTable** that uses **CellRenderer** and **CellEditor** and works fine but my problem is that when I fire a loof function to get the values edited of each row I get the same value for all rows which is the last edited value:

See this picture:

[image]

and this is how I get the values:

```
FillPointageCellEditorRenderer r = (FillPointageCellEditorRenderer) pTablePointage.getCellEditor(i, 2);

CompPointageCell object = (CompPointageCell) r.getCellEditorValue();
String hs = object.hs;
int chantier = object.selectedChantier;
int activity = object.selectedActivity;
```

FillPointageCellEditorRenderer: the class that implements TableCellRenderer and TableCellEditor.

how can I get the edited value of each row ?

Comment: Why would you use the JTable to get values and not the TableModel.

Comment: wow man thnx alot why I didn't think of that ?!!thnx again it works :)